# how to create a log file in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using code-igniter to develop my php application. I just wanna ask if there is a way I can make a generated error log file everytime the application encounters an error? I'm aware that it has a function of displaying errors on your page however i want to log my errors in a file as well is this possible using CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should have an automatic generated error log which is stored in your root folder.

Check for a file called "php_errorlog" or something similar to this.

You can then download it and open it with Notepad or any other editor.

Comment: ok thanks ill try looking for that one but am I correct? I'm seeing the errors because i configured my CI application correctly? so my problem is where the log file is located right?